# Using remarkable as my markdown processor in jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I am creating a site using jekyll.

I write my posts in [Remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) and when I look at it in blog it is parsed differently (probably because jekyll's default processor is kramdown).

Is it possible to change the markdown processor of jekyll to be that of remarkable so it is consistent?

Comment: Are you hosting the blog yourself or on GitHub Pages? Note that the latter only supports kramdown. https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

Comment: @approxiblue yes I am hosting it on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

You can define [custom Markdown Processors](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#custom-markdown-processors). However, they need to be defined in Rudy and Remarkable is a JavaScript library. Unless there is a Ruby wrapper, I doubt it will work well.

If you are hosting your Jekyll site on GitHub Pages, then you even have less control. Previously they offered both Kramdown and Redcarpet (via a config setting) but they removed Redcarpet support recently. As they control the code, you only get what they offer. Of course, if you are running Jekyll locally (or on your own server which you control) then you can make it use whatever Markdown implementation you want, but you need to do so with Ruby code. While not impossible, calling a non-Ruby library from Ruby would generally be excessive when there are various Ruby libraries which should work just fine.

Comment: So, do you think it is best to keep working with kramdown? Is there another option?